# Data Driven Map Book Using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, data-driven-pages, definition-query, administrative-boundaries

I am trying to create a Map book using ArcGIS. I am known to Data driven pages which create pages with GRID by GRID. But I want to create a Map book with the districts of Bangladesh. In every page I want to show one district. There are 64 District. Is there any way that will dynamically create the mapbook where in every page one district polygon will fit in one page while dynamically change few text field derived from data?

Comment: In looking at the free tutorial as suggested in the answer, pay particular attention to page definition queries and inserting dynamic text.

Answer (score 7):

You could consider looking at the free tutorial on [Creating Map Books Using Data Driven Pages](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseID=2152) that is offered by Esri.

You are asking about functionality that is all described in the Help.